# almacenar intentos en base de datos .net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

tengo una consulta estoy haciendo un sistema en .net y sql server , lo que quiero hacer es cuando un usuario se logee, almacene en mi base al usuario que entro o al usuario que erro su cuenta en el login y me diga cuantas veces entro o la hora, les agradecería por la ayuda .

```
   Private Sub BTNINGRESAR_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BTNINGRESAR.Click


    Try

        datos.Usuario_1 = TXTUSER.Text
        datos.Contraseña_1 = TXTPASS.Text

        If funcion.validar_sesion(datos) = True Then

            Preguntas.Show()
        ElseIf (contador = 3) Then

            MsgBox("Demasiado intentos fallidos")
            Me.Close()

        Else 'contar loos numeros de intentos


            MsgBox("Usuario o Contraseña Invalido, Intente de Nuevo")
            TXTUSER.Clear()
            TXTPASS.Clear()
            contador += 1

        End If


    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero necesitas una tabla para almacenar los logins, con un campo exito, otro de usuario, uno de clave y uno de fecha, para saber el intento, la hora y si tuvo exito o no a entrar al sistema.

Con la tabla creada en tu codigo haces un INSERT INTO en el sql cada vez que exista un intento de login

Te envio codigo

```
Imports System.Data
```

Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Private Sub BTNINGRESAR_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BTNINGRESAR.Click

```
Dim con As New SqlConnection
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand

Try

    con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=tuServidor;Initial Catalog=tuBaseDeDatos;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=tuUsuario;Password=tuClave"
    con.Open()
    cmd.Connection = con

    datos.Usuario_1 = TXTUSER.Text
    datos.Contraseña_1 = TXTPASS.Text

    If funcion.validar_sesion(datos) = True Then
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO INTENTOS (exito,usuario,clave) VALUES (1,datos.Usuario_1,datos.Contraseña_1)"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Preguntas.Show()
    ElseIf (contador = 3) Then
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO INTENTOS (exito,usuario,clave) VALUES (0,datos.Usuario_1,datos.Contraseña_1)"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("Demasiado intentos fallidos")
        Me.Close()

    Else 'contar loos numeros de intentos

        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO INTENTOS (exito,usuario,clave) VALUES (0,datos.Usuario_1,datos.Contraseña_1)"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        MsgBox("Usuario o Contraseña Invalido, Intente de Nuevo")
        TXTUSER.Clear()
        TXTPASS.Clear()
        contador += 1

    End If


Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
Finally
con.Close()
End Try
```

End Sub

Comment: Yo ya tengo la tabla login , donde tengo al usuario y la contraseña , tendria que agregar otra tablas ? deben estar relacionadas? , trabajo con capas

Comment: Si claro. Necesitas otra tabla donde almacenes los intentos de conexión.  Que es la tabla que te he indicado. La tienes relacionada con los logins y asi sabes quien hizo entrada correcta o fallida en ele sistema